# Grails GORM: groovy maps

Tags: grails, groovy, maps, grails-orm

Having the following domain class:

```
class Word {
    Map translations
    static hasMany = [translations: String]

    String toString(){
        id
    }
}
```

And some instances saved in grails bootstrap:

```
def word1 = new Word(translations: [en:"game"]);
word1.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

def word3 = new Word(translations: [en:"gate"]);
word3.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

def word2 = new Word(translations: [en:"life"]);
word2.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
```

It's not enabled to get `translations` field correctly. For example:

```
//input
println Word.findAll().each {
    println it.translations
}
//output
[:]
[:]
[:]
[1, 2, 3]
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You're defining two properties named `translations` with the Map and the hasMany.  I'm surprised that it would work at all but I would start with only having one and it looks like you want it to be the Map.

Comment: It doesn't matter, i think. It doesn't work even without hasMany. Check this: http://tinyurl.com/7ysmq2m

Comment: @tiktak That links seems to show it should work without the `hasMany`

Comment: @tiktak Exactly the same output?  Which version of Grails?

Comment: @tim_yates, exactly the same. Grails 2.0.0.

Comment: Tried it with Grails 2.0, and it works if you do: `new Word().with { translations = [ en:'tim' ] ; save( failOnError:true, flush:true ) }`

Comment: How does it know which `translations` you're setting then?  Based on type?

Comment: @JarredOlson I'm trying with no `hasMany` (as I believe this shouldn't be there as you say)

Comment: @tim_yates, awesome! It works (with and without hasMany)! But why? Any link?

Comment: @JarredOlson Think it's [related to this bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8479)  But map param constructors seem to work with Groovy 1.8.4...  Not sure where this is...  Might be worth posting it on the [Grails JIRA](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS)?

Answer (score 0):

The doc says:

If you want a simple map of string/value pairs GORM can map this with the following:

```
class Author {
    Map books // map of ISBN:book names
}
def a = new Author()
a.books = ["1590597583":"Grails Book"]
a.save()
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be

```
static hasMany = [translations: Map]
```

instead of

```
static hasMany = [translations: String]
```